# Loading dll functions into Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have VBA code which runs from Office 2003 to 2016 versions.

After moving to Office 365 the code fails to load functions from dll.

One of the functions as an example:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function hllapi_init Lib "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\libhllapi.dll" (ByVal tp As String) As Long
```

When calling the function, even though the full path is referenced in the declaration, Excel VBA shows

> runtime error 48 'file not found'

The file exists, as the code runs in previous versions of Office.

I searched for documentation on declaring functions and or api but found nothing specific to 365 version.

Also the `#if` statement, commonly used to adapt dll functions and api calls through 32bit and 64bit of Windows and Office paired (or not) with the `ptrsafe` command, seems to be ignored in the 365 version.

If the same declaration above is stated inside an `#if` condition at the top of module, VBA does not recognizes the function, returning

> vba compile error sub or function not defined

Running
Windows 10 **64bits**,
Office 365 **32bits**,
DLL is in the SYSWOW64 folder.

Comment: Well the obvious question is, did you check, if the path is really correct / if the `.dll` file is really there? I know my comment may sound demeaning, but it's better to measure twice and then cut and it gets the obvious out of the way :)

Comment: #If on its own won't work: what are you trying to use as the decision for conditional compilation?

Comment: @Rawrplus yes. The correct file is in the correct path. As I wrote: "obviously, the file exists, as the exact same code runs flawlessly in previous versions of office". Same machine, same excel file, open it in office 2013 and it works. Any machine which has the dll installed, open the excel file in any version but 365, the macro runs flawlessly...

Comment: @CharlesWilliams `#if win64 then 'dll function ptrsafe declaration #else 'dll function declaration #endif`. But, to be clear, the issue is not related directly with this, as the dll function can be declared out of any `#if` condfition, unconditionally. I mention it just as a plus... With or without `#if`, issue is about runtime error 48 specifically in excel 365 version.